# SQL Server 2008 R2 setup error on Windows Developer Preview

Tags: windows-8, sql-server-2008r2-express

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2(Express) on Windows Developer Preview (32bit) but getting a strange error:

```
---------------------------
```

### Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup

SQL Server 2008 R2 setup requires Microsoft .NET Framework and an updated Windows Installer to be installed.

### To enable the .NET Framework Core role, click OK. To exit Setup, click Cancel.

### OK   Cancel

Even I clicked OK but the error comes again and again. 
Do you know the reason and the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed .NET framework 3.5 SP1 and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps to install SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows 8

1. Control Panel
2. Turn On or Off Feature
3. Select Dotnet - Need to have Dotnet 3.5 SP1
4. Restart your computer
5. Install SQL Server 2008/R2
6. Smile :)